# PHP Eval alternative to generate a dynamic if condition

Tags: php, eval

I have the following php code where I'm trying to generate a dynamic if condition using eval:

```
$categoryId = $_REQUEST['category_id'];
$locationId = $_REQUEST['location_id'];

$recordId = 1;

$criteria = [(!empty($categoryId) ? '(isInCategory($recordId, $categoryId))' : ''),
             (!empty($locationId) ? '(isInLocation($recordId, $locationId))' : '')];

$check = implode(' && ', array_filter($criteria));

// $check will be  
// (isInCategory($recordId, $categoryId)) && (isInLocation($recordId, $locationId))
// if $categoryId and $locationId are not empty

if(eval("return $check;")) 
{ 
    echo 'true'; 
}
else
{
   echo 'false';
}
```

The problem is the entire code itself is within an eval statement so basically I'm ending up with an eval inside an eval which is throwing an error - can't really troubleshoot the error because all I get is a friendly error page so I'm assuming that is the case i.e. you cant use eval inside another eval???

I'm forced to use a propriety product so this is my limitation. Is there a way I can refactor the eval in the above if statement via some other technique.

I read some stuff about using call_user_func() but I'm new to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have just created remote code execution. Just forget that the statement `eval()` even exists, and then force yourself to ask the question, how could I do it without eval?

Comment: @Dharman I have no idea what you mean by remote code execution. Please can you explain and demonstrate using some code example.

Comment: Just google it. What you are doing with eval is basically letting anyone from the web execute any piece of code they want on your server. This is never what you want, because the whole server is compromised.